# How do DocumentDBAttribute bindings respond to throttling?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have azure functions (C# v1 functions--non scripted) that use DocumentDBAttribute bindings for both reading and writing documents.  How do those bindings respond to throttling in the following situations?

- Writing an item by adding it to an ICollector
- Reading an item by providing an Id

This is for functions v1.

First case:

```
        //input binding
        [DocumentDB(ResourceNames.APCosmosDBName, 
          ResourceNames.EpisodeOfCareCollectionName,
          ConnectionStringSetting = "APCosmosDB",
          CreateIfNotExists = true)] ICollector<EOC> eoc,
        //...
        eoc.Add(new EOC()); //what happens here if throttling is occuring?
```

Second case:

```
[DocumentDB(ResourceNames.ORHCasesDBName, ResourceNames.ORHCasesCollectionName, ConnectionStringSetting = "ORHCosmosDBCases", CreateIfNotExists = true, Id = "{id}")] string closedCaseStr,
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both input and output bindings use CosmosDB SDK which has the [retry mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet) in place.

By default, SDK retries 9 times on a throttled result, after that, the exception is bubbled and you Function will error. Depending on the trigger type, it will fail HTTP call, put the message back to the queue etc.

The retries respect the timing recommendation returned by Cosmos DB:

> When a client is sending requests faster than the allowed rate, the service will return HttpStatusCode 429 (Too Many Request) to rate limit the client. The current implementation in the SDK will then wait for the amount of time the service tells it to wait and retry after the time has elapsed.

At the moment, there is no way to configure the bindings with a policy other than default.

Comment: Is there anyway to configure how the retries occur?  Does time pass between retries?

Comment: You could, of course, catch the exception, and retry yourself - but be careful, you probably don't want your function to run for longer than 5 minutes or it could get killed.